# Group and sort map in a predefined order

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is an extension to group my tasks

```
/// EXTENSION

  Map<K, List<T>> groupBy<T, K>(K key(T e)) {
    Map<K, List<T>> map = {};

    for (final element in this) {
      var list = map.putIfAbsent(key(element as T), () => []);
      list.add(element);
    }
    return map;
  }
```

```
/// CODE

final List<String> requiredPrioritySortOrder = ['df','sc','de','dd'];
final Map<String, List<Task>> tasksByPriority = _selectedTasks.groupBy<Task, String>((e) => e.priority);
```

As a result, I have received a map but the sort order change every time after the task update.

How to sort **tasksByPriority** Map by key in a predefined order (requiredPrioritySortOrder).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am already find a solution but maybe there is another way?

```
_selectedTasks.groupBy<Task, String>((e) => e.priority, order:['sc','df']);
```

```
  Map<K, List<T>> groupBy<T, K>(K key(T e), {Iterable order = const []}) {
    Map<K, List<T>> mapped = {};
    Map<K, List<T>> sorted = {};

    for (final e in this) {
      List list = mapped.putIfAbsent(key(e as T), () => []);
      list.add(e);
    }

    if (order.isNotEmpty) {
      order.forEach((e) {
        if (mapped[e] != null) {
          sorted[e] = mapped[e]!;
        }
      });

      return sorted;
    }

    return mapped;
  }
```